# Call to a member function first() on array Laravel Livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm trying to make a multi-svg selection system with `Laravel 7` and `Livewire`.

When clicking on a SVG shape (acting like a button), I get a `Call to a member function first() on array` error, with not much in the debug panel as it's highlighting a closing div (almost end of file). By the way, there is no explicit `first()' call in my code.

Here is my front-end component code

```
@if(count($sectors) > 0)
    <div class="svg-container">
      <svg preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice" viewbox="0 0 800 525" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
              @foreach($sectors as $sector)
                  <polygon wire:key="sector{{$sector->id}}" wire:click="selectSector({{ $sector->id }})" class="hover:cursor-pointer" points="{{$sector->points}}" fill="@if(in_array($sector->id, $selected_sectors)) {{$sector->hover_color}} @else {{$sector->color}} @endif" opacity="0.5" onMouseOver="this.style.fill='@if(in_array($sector->id, $selected_sectors)) {{$sector->color}} @else {{$sector->hover_color}} @endif'" onMouseOut="this.style.fill='@if(in_array($sector->id, $selected_sectors)) {{$sector->hover_color}} @else {{$sector->color}} @endif'"/>
              @endforeach
        @foreach($empties as $empty)
                  <polygon wire:key="empty{{$sector->id}}" points="{{$empty->points}}" fill="{{ $empty->empty_color ?? 'white' }}" opacity="0.5"/>
              @endforeach
          </svg>
    </div>
    @endif
```

and here is the back-end

```
public function mount($event){
        $this->event = $event;
        $this->filter = "no";

        $this->all_tickets = TicketsModel::where('event_id', $this->event)
            ->where('isAvailableToPurchase', 1)
            ->where('isBought', 0)
            ->where('locked', 0)
            ->get();
        
        $tickets_qty_groups = $this->all_tickets->groupBy('group_id');
        $this->groups = collect($tickets_qty_groups);
        
}

public function render(){
        $this->sectors = collect([]);
        $this->empties = collect([]);
        
        $test = EventsModel::find($this->event);
        $this->event_name = $test->title;
        $this->event_date = $test->start;
        
        $seatmap = $test->seat_map;
        $map = new SeatMapModel;
        $this->seatmap_image = $map->getImage($seatmap);
        $m = new SectorsModel;
        $sectors = SectorsModel::where('seat_map_id', $seatmap)->get();
        
        foreach($sectors as $sector){
            if($this->all_tickets->contains('sector_id', $sector->id)){
                $this->sectors = $this->sectors->push($sector);
            }else{
                $this->empties = $this->empties->push($sector);
            }
        }
        return view('livewire.components.seat-map-viewer');
}

public function selectSector($sector_id){
        $this->sector_clicked = $sector_id;
        $this->selected_sectors[] = $sector_id;
        $this->selected_sectors = array_unique($this->selected_sectors);
    }
```

Thanks.

Update 1:

Stack Trace:

```
  @if(count($sectors) > 0)
    <div class="svg-container">
      <svg preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice" viewbox="0 0 800 525" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
              @foreach($sectors as $sector)
                  <polygon wire:key="sector{{$sector->id}}" wire:click="selectSector({{ $sector->id }})" class="hover:cursor-pointer" points="{{$sector->points}}" fill="@if(in_array($sector->id, $selected_sectors)) {{$sector->hover_color}} @else {{$sector->color
              @endforeach
        @foreach($empties as $empty)
                  <polygon wire:key="empty{{$sector->id}}" points="{{$empty->points}}" fill="{{ $empty->empty_color ?? 'white' }}" opacity="0.5"/>
              @endforeach
          </svg>
    </div>
    @endif
    </div>
  <div>
    <select class="select input-group" name="filter" wire:model="filter">
      <option value="no">{{__('No filter')}}</option>
      <option value="price">{{__('Order by price')}}</option>
      <option value="rating">{{__('Order by reseller rating')}}</option>
      <option value="2">{{__('2 tickets or more')}}</option>
      <option value="3">{{__('3 tickets or more')}}</option>
      <option value="4">{{__('4 tickets or more')}}</option>
    </select>
    <div class="flex overflow-x-scroll pb-10 hide-scroll-bar">
      <div class="flex flex-nowrap lg:ml-40 md:ml-20 ml-10 ">
        @foreach($groups as $group)
          <livewire:components.ticket-card :max="count($group)" :ticket_id="$group->first()->id" :event_name="$event_name" :event_date="$event_date" :wire:key="$group->first()->id" >
        @endforeach
      </div>
    *</div>*
  </div>
</div>
```

I put * so we can see which line is highlighted.

Comment: Can you post the entire trace?

Comment: You wrote, `there is no explicit first() call in my code` but there is one, 3 lines above the closing `</div>` you mentioned. `$group->first()->id` assumes that `$group` is an object, but it mustn't be. You can do `dd($group)` to confirm this, and work back from there to determine why those values are arrays and not objects as your code expects.